# Referencing members of an object within a class type vector

Tags: c++, class, vector, reference

Ok guys this problem has been bugging me all day and I cant seem find a solution. I know Its a long post but I would be very grateful for any help you can offer.
I am working on a chatbot program that reads in from a .dat file to populate a library of keywords. Taking an object orientated approach I defined a class called "Keyword", the class definition is shown below:

```
class Keyword
{
public:   
    //_Word holds keyword 
    vector<string> _Word;
    //_Resp holds strings of responses
    vector<string> _Resp;
    //_Antymn holds words that are the opposite to keyword
    vector<string> _Antymn;

    // Constructor
    Keyword()
    {
        // Clears members when new instance created
        _Word.clear();
        _Resp.clear();
        _Antymn.clear();
    }
};
```

Therefore every time a new keyword is found in the .dat file, a new instance of the class keyword must be created. To store all these instances of keyword I create another vector but this time of type Keyword and call it library:

```
typedef vector<Keyword> Lib;
Lib library;// this is the same as saying vector<Keyword> library
```

Now this is the problem I have: After a user inputs a string I need to check if that string contains a keyword from the library i.e. I need to see if the string in _Word appears in the user input. Looking at it from a hierarchy of vectors you have:

```
The top level --> libary //*starting point
                 --> Keyword
                    --> _Word
                      -->"A single string" <-- I want to reference this one
                    --> _Resp
                      -->"Many strings"
                    --> _Antymn
                      -->"Many strings"
```

Phew! I hope that made sense. 
This is the code I started to write:

```
size_t User::findKeyword(Lib *Library)
{
    size_t found;
    int count = 0;

    for(count = 0; count<Library->size(); count++)
    {
      found = _Input.find(Library->at(count)); // this line needs to reference _Word from each keyword instance within library
      if(found!= string.npos)
        return found;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried to use the "operator[]" method but that doesnt seem to do what I want either.
Does anyone have any idea ? I would be very suprised if it couldn't be done. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make it: `found = _Input.find(Library->at(count)._Word);` to access the member variable `_Word`

Comment: why is _word a vector? If you are only storing one keyword per instance of `Keyword` then it should just be of type string.

Comment: Note that names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: Hey Papergay, I have tried this before posting but it kept throwing me an error. Could it be down to what Charlie has said ?

Comment: @Papergay:  You can make your comment an answer.  I would upvote it.

Comment: Also note that your `Keyword` constructor is useless, the members are already clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your code to this:

```
for(count = 0; count<Library->size(); count++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < Library->at(count)._Word.size(); ++j){
        found = _Input.find(Library->at(count)._Word[j]);
                                              ^^^^^^^^^
        if(found!= string.npos)
             return found;
    }
}
```

in order to access the member variable and to iterate through your vector of strings. `Library->at(count)` is an object of class the `Keyword`.
I assume that `_Input.find()` takes a string as argument.

If your `Keyword` instance stores just one keyword, you might as well change it to `string _Word`, so that you wold not need the second loop.

```
for(count = 0; count<Library->size(); count++)
{
    found = _Input.find(Library->at(count)._Word);
    if(found!= string.npos)
        return found;
}
```

And to enforce the other comments: you should not use the preliminary `_`-underscore in your variable names since they are reserved by the implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much! _Input.find() does take a string as an argument. I was missing the _Word[j] piece off the end.

Comment: This is actively harmful. `vector::at` will make an out-of-bounds check and throw and is only recommended for debugging. So is rewriting `std::find` or unnecessary passing of pointers instead of references.

Comment: Im not sure, but can you even do `Library->[index]` ? Or how do you call that operator with pointers?

Comment: Btw, you should not neglect what [pmr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12113866/1548637) is pointing out.

Comment: @Papergay No, you can do `Library->operator[](index);`

Comment: Okay thx! I totally forgot that you can call the operators explicitly :p

Comment: @Papergay the reason for using a vector of strings for _Word is because I intend to include synonyms at a later date. That way I dont need to create additional antynms and reponses for every new keyword that is added. Eventually I will have to use the nested for loop. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 3):

A bunch of issues first:

- identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by a capital 
  letter are reserved in any namespace
- the `clear()` call in the `Keyword` constructor are pointless and possibly 
  harmful to optimization

Why is `word_` a `vector`? I though it is one keyword.

```
struct Keyword
{
    // real words as identifiers, no underscores 
    //anywhere if they are public
    std::string word;
    std::vector<std::string> respones;
    std::vector<std::string> antonym;
};


typedef std::vector<Keyword> Lib;



/// finding a keyword
#include <algorithm>

Lib::iterator findKeyword(const Lib& l, const std::string& x) {
  return std::find_if(begin(l), end(l), 
                      [](const Keyword& kw) { return kw.word == x; })
  // if stuck on non C++11 compiler use a Functor
}
```

Comment: @pmr-thank you for your help. I have now removed the underscores from the class members. I originally used them to differentiate between local variables and class members. The clear() method was only included to initialise the vectors. Isnt this necessary ? Thank you.

Comment: @EdwardPaul A good convention is `m_membername` or `membername_`. It is important for private members to avoid ambiguity between a member function with the same name, e.g. the getter `size()` and the private member `size_`. The `vector::clear` is not necessary. A default constructed vector is empty. It also looks like you have `using namespace std` in a header. This is also bad.